# json glib compilation error -- template command not found

Tags: json, bash, ubuntu-12.04, glib

I'm trying to compile the jsonglib .after executing the ./configure and i used make file to compile the json-glib .but the following error is displaying in my terminal ...

```
    GEN      stamp-enum-types
```

/bin/bash: line 1: --template: command not found
make[2]: *** [stamp-enum-types] Error 127

what im missing ? ..pls help me get rid out of this error .

Answer (score 0):

So you need install make (GNU make??) first.

If you have installed, the error shows the ./configure can't find the make command, then you need put full path of make command in your PATH env.